# What is the size of single attribute in the GAE datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

What is the size of single attribute in the GAE datastore? I mean because of using JDO, I may store a object with attributes like key, string, date... So how can I know those size of data or the limit size of those data?

Answer (score 0):

> maximum entity size   1 megabyte

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits

For individual fields within an entity, you can find the value limits here:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Properties_and_Value_Types